# Duplicate notifications on iOS17

Tags: apple-push-notifications, ios17

In our app we receive duplicate notifications on **iOS17**. This is the notification body:

```
{"aps":
  {
    "id": "0800546c-a87f-4bb4-bca4-bf6cf616c8aa",
    "alert":"3"
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

**The "id" property is causing the problem. But only on iOS 17.** Remove or rename the id property and the problem is solved. Put anything in there and there is no problem, but "id" will cause the notification to come in numerous times.

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue and I couldn't find much information about it. Do you have any further insights as to why this has helped?